# Expanding a div vertically

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with divs not expanding vertically where there are anchors with padding inside.

Since the explanation is not the best one, I've recreated problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/uF6KN/3/
Basically, I want blue anchors to have to same top coordinate as a blue button. I've tried somethings but got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

I not really that proficient in CSS so I might be missing a simple thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 #d_float_right a {display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a {
 float: right;
}
```

should fix it. changing the `a` from a `inline` to a `block` element. Setting display:block on a would also make it a block element but would put each on `a` newline

Answer (score 1):

`#d_float_right a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}`